EEVEE settings for curve subdivisions, why capped?

Why are EEVEE's curve render subdivision settings capped at 3?
Is there a way to get arround this cap - in EEVEE?

I do know that in cycles, i would have an uncapped setting for this, i would like to use EEVEE tho.



Hello and welcome, that's just a additional subdivision on top of the curves subdivisions. Curves subdivision can be change inside the properties panel of the curves or by using a subdivision modifier

Thanks! Where would i find the curve's properties panel, if the curve is a geometry-nodes hair curve?

Geometry nodes has a spline resolution node that you can use or a resample node, it all depends on the way you are using it
